# Roots of $P(P(x))$ in function of the roots of $P(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let's suppose $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n\ge 5$ with integer coefficients. It has $n$ integer roots, let's say $x_1,x_2,\cdots ,x_n$. We know that $x_1=0$. Find all roots of $P(P(x))$ in function of $x_1,x_2,\cdots , x_n$

So due to the fact that we know that $x_1=0$, we can write $P(x)=x\cdot Q(x)$, and the roots of $Q$ are $x_2\cdots,x_n$.
Than $P(P(x))=P(x)\cdot Q(P(x))$.
But the roots of $Q$ are $x_2,\cdots , x_n$, thus the roots of $Q(P(x))$ are the points where $P(x)=x_i$ for $i$ between $2$ and $n$...

This doesn't seem correct, can someone help me? I haven't used the fact that the roots are integers or the fact that the coefficients are integers...

Comment: This is an Olympiad problem.

Comment: Please provide more details, for instance, what are your thoughts about the question, what you have tried, where you are stuck.

Comment: @Friedrich Which one?

Comment: @SahibaArora It's done